# Footer's New Background Image and Height

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: footer]

As shown in the image, the footer is taller then the background image. (small lighter blue strip along the bottom) The footer is 509.917px when the image is only 500px.

That can be fixed by setting the `padding-top` on the `#footer` to 0.

OR

Lowering the `padding` on the `.footerwrap` down to 10px.

I personally thing the first method is the better option.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks. Will push a fix soon.